# Cannot use javahl nor command line svn client with ant 1.7.1 on window 2008 server

Tags: cruisecontrol

I have an ant build.xml like this which is launch from cruisecontrol config.xml

```
<!-- Use the properties from the props file -->
<property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>   
<path id="svnant.classpath">   
    <pathelement location="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib"/>   
    <fileset dir="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib/">    
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>   
    </fileset>  
</path> 
<taskdef name="svn" classname="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${work.folder}"/>
</target>
<svn javahl="false">
    <status path="${basedir}" revisionProperty="svn.revision" />
    <export srcUrl="${svn.baseurl}/test/test.barFiles" destPath="${work.folder}/test/test.barFiles"/>
</svn>
```

I have subversion 1.5.7 and svnant 1.0.0, I copied svnant.jar, svnClientAdapter.jar, svnjavahl.jar into my ant_home\lib folder.  I also add them on the path and classpath, but when I ran the build, I'm still getting the "Cannot use javahl nor command line svn client" on the 
Any idea?  I do not want to use javahl.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue due to some compatibility issues. I ended up using the `<exec>` tag

```
<exec executable="svn.exe">
<arg value="up"/>
<arg value ="--revision=head"/>
</exec>
```

That should help.
Thanks,
Scott